# Compare html table columns to php Query columns and hide some specific ones

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 for one of my websites. My home page has a table that displays data from table A. I have a backend where an admin can hide certain columns so they won't show on the home page table. The way I built this is I have a table called hidden_columns. When the admin check a column to hide. the column gets added to the hidden_columns table. If they want to unhide it, they would check it and the column will be deleted from the hidden columns table. Backend is working fine. The problem is how would I go about hiding the columns that are in the hidden_columns table from the home page where the data is displayed?

This is my code that displays data in the home page
controller

```
$tables = TableModel::get();
$hiddenCols = HiddenColumn::lists('col_name');
return view('view path', compact('tables','hiddenCols'));
```

Then in my view I just run a foreach loop on the tables object and display the data.

Thank you

Comment: your question is not clear. Why don't remove the cols in hiddenCols from your table? iterate over your table and if the same col is in hiddenCols just remove it. Another way (probably better) is to do it on the client side with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are several ways you could go about this. Personally, I would create a list of possible columns somewhere (your choice if static or dynamic through db for example), remove all the hidden columns of the possible columns in the controller and return the remaining columns to the view. If you name your columns the same as the fields of the TableModel, it will be even easier.

```
$rows = TableModel::get();
// as static approach - or you go dynamic with another table, what would be better
$allCols = array('name_col1', 'name_col2', 'name_col3');
$hiddenCols = HiddenColumn::lists('col_name');
$remainingCols = array_except($allCols, $hiddenCols);
return view('view path', compact('rows','remainingCols'));
```

In view you could iterate through the remaining columns and display them. If you choose the names appropriately, you can use the following:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach($remainingCols as $col)
            <th>{{ $col }}</th> // maybe use some language files here
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($rows as $row)
            <tr>
                @foreach($remainingCols as $col)
                    <td>{{ $row->$col }}</td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: Going the way through JavaScript as suggested in the comment above is no valid option. The explanation of the feature says that an admin is required to hide/show columns, what means, that this is probably a security relevant feature. By using JavaScript, all the content has to be printed and manipulated afterwards, what basically gives you either the chance to read the source code if the columns are hidden only or race (e.g. pause) the JavaScript before it manipulates the table. So make sure you never do such stuff client side if you care about users being able to read things they should not.